# How to split a column in pandas using separator and also assign custom unique name in the process?

Tags: python, pandas, split

I want to split a hybrid block and assign letters to each column separately:

```
M1 M2 M3 M4 hybrid_block S1 S2 S3 S4                                                          
A  T  T  A   A|C         C  G  C  T 
T  G  C  T   T|A         A  T  A  T 
C  A  A  C   C|G         G  A  C  G 
G  T  G  T   G|T         C  T  T  T
```

Using the following code:

```
d1 = pd.concat([
    df.filter(like='M'),
    df.hybrid_block.str.split('|', expand=True).rename(columns='H{}'.format),
    df.filter(like='S')
], axis=1)
```

Output I am getting:

```
M1 M2 M3 M4 H0  H1 S1 S2 S3 S4                                                          
A  T  T  A   A  C  C  G  C  T 
T  G  C  T   T  A  A  T  A  T 
C  A  A  C   C  G  G  A  C  G 
G  T  G  T   G  T  C  T  T  T
```

I rather want:

```
M1 M2 M3 M4 H_x  H_y S1 S2 S3 S4                                                          
A  T  T  A   A  C  C  G  C  T 
T  G  C  T   T  A  A  T  A  T 
C  A  A  C   C  G  G  A  C  G 
G  T  G  T   G  T  C  T  T  T
```

Also, if there are more than 1 hybrid block I want to split all of them accordingly, by assigning a unique names like `h1_x and h1_y` for the first block and `h2_x, h2_y` for the 2nd block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `pandas`

using a dictionary instead of a format function in the rename method

```
d1 = pd.concat([
    df.filter(like='M'),
    df.hybrid_block.str.split('|', expand=True).rename(columns={0: 'H_x', 1: 'H_y'}),
    df.filter(like='S')
], axis=1)
```

## `numpy`

not sure how many times you are going to do this or how big your data is, but this should be quicker

```
def split_block(df):
    v = df.values
    i = df.columns.get_loc('hybrid_block')
    col_left = df.columns[:i].tolist()
    col_right = df.columns[i + 1:].tolist()
    col = col_left + ['H_x', 'H_y'] + col_right
    h = np.array(np.core.defchararray.split(v[:, i].astype(str), '|').tolist())
    data = np.hstack([v[:, :i], h, v[:, i+1:]])
    return pd.DataFrame(data, columns=col)

d1 = split_block(df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

you can also use [.str.extract()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) method:

```
In [107]: d1 = pd.concat([
     ...:     df.filter(like='M'),
     ...:     df.hybrid_block.str.extract(r'(?P<H_x>[^\|]*)\|(?P<H_y>[^\|]*)', expand=True),
     ...:     df.filter(like='S')
     ...: ], axis=1)
     ...:

In [108]: d1
Out[108]:
  M1 M2 M3 M4 H_x H_y S1 S2 S3 S4
0  A  T  T  A   A   C  C  G  C  T
1  T  G  C  T   T   A  A  T  A  T
2  C  A  A  C   C   G  G  A  C  G
3  G  T  G  T   G   T  C  T  T  T
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to automate finding the hybrid columns and splitting them, this would work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'m1': ["A", "T"], 'hybrid1': ["A|C", "T|A"], 's1': ["C",    "A"], 'hybrid2': ["B|D", "F|Z"], 'hybrid3': ["V|K", "M|L"]})
for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    if (df.ix[:, i].str.len() >1).any():
        df_i = pd.DataFrame(df.ix[:, i].str.split('|', expand=True).rename(columns={0: (list(df)[i])+'_x', 1: (list(df)[i])+'_y'}))
        df = df.drop(df.columns[i], axis = 1)
        df = pd.concat([df_i, df], axis=1)
```